# How is redirect on steam third parties sites working?

Tags: redirect, steam, steam-web-api

I started inspecting third parties steam sites
and I found interesting thing.

Example site: https://stntrading.eu
This site require steam login.

When I try to check for example this url:
https://stntrading.eu/item/csgo/Danger+Zone+Case
without being logged on site, I got (most sometimes) redirected to https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login.

But how is this thing working?

Backend way:

```
https://wheregoes.com/trace/20224247383/ -- says, there are no redirects
```

Frontend way:

```
When I disable javascript on site -- Site is still redirecting.
```

HTML way:

```
"<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="time; URL=new_url" />" -- is not in HTML
```

Redirect works only some times, so I even tried my own script to find backend redirects (in case ip get on some kind of "login whitelist" after x tries to load site without logging in)
But I found nothing.

So, what is way how is this working?

Answer (score 0):

ive been trying to access the same site and have been running into trouble; ive tried the same methods you described, they didnt work, ive tried using proxies cuz i thought i might be rate limited, it didnt work, i cant find any relevant tags in the html or anything interesting in the js, none of the event listeners seem like theyd do anything to cause a redirect, etc.

the only thing that came close was opening the main site in a request session and using the cookies/session parameters/whatever else that got loaded to load the actual item page i wanted to scrape but that only worked ~50% of the time. at some point that completely stopped working too. it seems like the site is bugged cuz theres no good reason for it to be behaving in a way that outwardly seems this random

if this helps, the /backend/search?query= path does provide basic information about given items including their sell price (but not the price the site buys them at), thats the best i could find

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).